# View Not attached to window manager. With android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-relativelayout

I am trying to use a relative layout in my service and adding it to the window manager. However it gives me this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13199): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.prototypetest.GestureService@4279f058 with Intent { cmp=com.example.prototypetest/.GestureService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2571)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at com.example.prototypetest.GestureService.onStartCommand(GestureService.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(13199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2554)   ... 10 more
```

This is the code that causes the issue.

```
serviceLayout.addView(mView,rightViewParams);
wm.updateViewLayout(serviceLayout, p);
wm.addView(serviceLayout, p);
```

Wm is the window manager that is being used with a service. Are you not allowed to use a layout with a service?

Thanks

Comment: services do not have a UI

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: Of course they dont have an UI, but you can show a window/layout by using the draw-over-other-apps ! I have this issue, after inflating and adding the view I get that exception.

Comment: what we have to do to avoid this crash in services. @Luser_k

Comment: Create a custom view and add it to the window. Inside your custom view use the callbacks onAttachToWindow(...) and onDetachToWindw(...).

Comment: @Luser_k can you please elaborate above solution as i am getting same crash.